# What is the purpose of additional_data column in quote_item table in magento2

Tags: magento2, additional-information

I want to set custom data in quote item from plugin. i have shipping rates in an array.If i set data rates array array in  addition_data from that plugin it appears correctly in checkout_onepage_controller_success_action event.
Is that correct way to set custom data inside addition_data ?

i am doing something like this in plugin

```
$shipping_rates[$shiping['method_name']] = $shiping['fee'];
$item->setadditionalData($shipping_rates);
```

If i am doing wrong then please suggent me anyother way so that i set any custom array from plugin and retrieve that custom array during checkout event.
I also want to know the exact purpose of additiol_data colum in quote _item table.

Comment: No answers so far?

Comment: i believe this column is to add custom attributes data.